# Partition created by Gparted not effective when rebooting into Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, gparted

I am trying to install a dual boot machine (HP Zbook15) with ubuntu 14.04 next to a windows 7. The laptop came preinstalled with the Windows partition taking up the whole HDD (750Gb) (apart from a 1Gb SYSTEM partition). I tried to reduce this to 100Gb to free up space for a ext4 for Ubuntu and a NTFS data partition to be shared between both OS's.

Unable to reduce to shrink the partition using Disk Management in Windows. It didnt allow me to go beyond the halfway point. Note that I reduced the pagefile to 1Gb (i have 32G of RAM) and turned off the hibernation. So the complete Windows install is about 30Gb.

Trying to partition using GParted via a Ubuntu Live CD, let me reduce this volume to 100GB however and also create an ext4 (also 100Gb) and an NTFS partition (rest of the disk).

And now comes the problem: as soon as I reboot into Windows, all of these changes are gone and the C drive is again taking up all the HDD.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that you applied the settings in GParted? GParted does not create the partitions "on the fly". You need to press some sort of Apply button, can't remember the name of it.

Comment: Be aware that, shrinking your windows partition in GParted, may result in dataloss or even an unbootable Windows.

Comment: lol ;) As soon as I posted this question i was thinking this is the first remark i am going to get. I should have put this is in my desription also but I thought it to be so obvious that I didnt bother. But anyway: Yes I clicked the Apply button.

Comment: And windows reboots without any problem. It is just that the partitions I create in GParted are not there!

Comment: Hehe. No idea then. But reducing the Windows Partition size using GParted, is a bad idea. The safest way is from within Windows Disk Management. There might be a good reason to why you can not reduce it that much. :)

Comment: I dont care about Windows. This is a brand new laptop. I dont want to be "forced" to give 300 Gb partition to a system that I will only every now and then use. Moreover I always use a separate DATA partition, so I am also using that space to give to DATA.

Comment: I have used GParted to resize Windows NTFS partitions without any problem.  There is one catch though in that if you move the start of the partition you might need to restore boot using the Windows install or repair media.

Answer (score 0):

I'we had pretty much the same problem, so after a few retryes that ended the same I just let Ubuntu handle the disk with its recommended options. Somehow if I did'nt try making a fwap file it worked. After a couple of reboots to both, and letting windows refind its now smaller HD I could resize and create a Swap partition!
I think that the OEM install of windows dosn't fully comply with the specs for partitions, and Ubuntu doing something with special options when allowed fixed that inconsistency. So try the default Let Ubuntu (Keep Windows and resize for Ubuntu) do its diskmagic - and when it all works apply the settings you want!
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is becoming more and more finicky with age, trying to get rid of these pesky Linux installs... ;-)

Is this an EFI system?  Because they are *even more* finicky...  Read up on EFI/uEFI/xEFI before trying anything else!

If not, I would: do as much in windows as I can, reboot, reload windows again *and only then* reboot into gparted live, do some stuff, reboot into windows *again* and see if it worked this time.

Please post back here if that works better...

P.S. I have a trick up my sleeve making windows behave more socially with other OSes using the "diag" flag for a partition...